# Site shrinks left on iPhone

Tags: css, iphone, viewport

I have a site—actually several sites—that when viewed in portrait mode on the iPhone shrinks left. (It doesn't happen in a browser when it's at a small width or in chrome's device emulator.)

[Here's one of the sites](http://www.elizabethbemis.com)...
[Here's another](http://www.dianaquincy.com)

This is my viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Any thoughts on what might be causing this, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `overflow-x:hidden` in `<body>` to remove horizontal scroll.

It is caused by the `<li>` of the `<nav>`. If you remove `float:left` and add `display:inline` you do not even need the `overflow-x:hidden` in `<body>`.

Comment: THAT WAS IT!  :D Thank you!! You are my hero!

Comment: Little advise: FirefoxDeveloperEdition has a lot integrated tools and they are very useful for this Kind of problems :)